# Android Google Maps, how to make each Marker InfoWindow open different Activity?

Tags: android, google-maps

I use following code segment for display several locations on google map. I get those coordinates as a array. After displaying markers on the map i want to go for a activity after clicking Infowindows of marker. Each infowindow of single marker should have different activity after clicking it. I have 4 markers and i want to access 4 different activities by clicking infowindow. How should i implement this. Thank you

My code of put markers on map

```
     Marker a1 = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(a)
                .title(arr[0])
                .snippet(arr[1])            );
       Marker b1 = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(b)
                .title(arr[9])
                .snippet(arr[10])                 );
        Marker c1= googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(c)
                .title(arr[18])
                .snippet(arr[19]));
        Marker d1= googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(d)
                .title(arr[27])
                .snippet(arr[28]));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a HashMap to store the marker ID and it's corresponding identification of which Activity it should open.

Then, use a `OnInfoWindowClickListener` to get the event of a user clicking the info window, and use the HashMap to determine which Activity to open.

Declare the HashMap as an instance variable:

```
//Declare HashMap to store mapping of marker to Activity
HashMap<String, String> markerMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Then, each time you add a Marker, make an entry in the HashMap:

```
        String id = null;

        Marker a1 = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(a)
                .title(arr[0])
                .snippet(arr[1]));

        id = a1.getId();
        markerMap.put(id, "a1");

        Marker b1 = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(b)
                .title(arr[9])
                .snippet(arr[10]));

        id = b1.getId();
        markerMap.put(id, "b1");

        Marker c1= googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(c)
                .title(arr[18])
                .snippet(arr[19]));

        id = c1.getId();
        markerMap.put(id, "c1");

        Marker d1= googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(d)
                .title(arr[27])
                .snippet(arr[28]));

        id = d1.getId();
        markerMap.put(id, "d1");
    }
```

And then define the info window click listener:

```
    googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

            String m = markerMap.get(marker.getId());

            if (m.equals("a1")){
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityA1.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            else if (m.equals("b1")){
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityB1.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            else if (m.equals("c1")){
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityC1.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            else if (m.equals("d1")){
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityD1.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: @janithachanuka No problem!  Glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 0):

I can see that multiple fields are linked:

- Title
- Snippet
- Position
- Activity

Here's how you can accomplish this in code:

1. Create a custom class:

   ```
   public static class MyMarker {

       Marker marker;
       MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
       Class activity;

       public MyMarker(String title, String snippet, LatLng position, Class activity) {
           // MarkerOptions
           options.title(title)
                   .snippet(snippet)
                   .position(position);

           // Target activity
           this.activity = activity;
       }

       // Compare Marker variable instead of MyMarker
       @Override
       public boolean equals(Object o) {
           return o != null && o.equals(marker);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Prepare markers:

   ```
   final List<MyMarker> myMarkers = new ArrayList<>();
   myMarkers.add(new MyMarker("title1", "snippet1", new LatLng(10, 10), MainActivity1.class));
   myMarkers.add(new MyMarker("title2", "snippet2", new LatLng(20, 20), MainActivity2.class));
   ```
3. Add markers to GoogleMap and save the returned object:

   ```
   for (MyMarker myMarker : myMarkers) {
       myMarker.marker = googleMap.addMarker(myMarker.options);
   }
   ```
4. Add a marker click listener to your map:

   ```
   googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
           // Will use the overridden equals method
           int index = myMarkers.indexOf(marker);
           if (index != -1) {
               // Considering that MainActivity is the current activity
               Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, myMarkers.get(index).activity);
               startActivity(intent);
           }
           return false;
       }
   });
   ```

The above listener will look for the clicked marker in your added markers array and if it's there, will start the associated activity.

Comment: I did't try this. But u have provided a clear answer appreciate ur work (y)