# How to save information of markers of Map v2 so that it can be retrieve on marker click

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, supportmapfragment

I am making an app which has map v2 and I am displaying multiple pins successfully. I have followed an tutorial which was just displaying the pin/markers on map v2.

Through service I am getting information of Marker showing the Hotels location on map . The service is sending me the information which include Hotel Name, Location , Food , Services , rating and Latitude and longitude.so let me explain what I have done so far

what I am doing is getting each  hotel specification in my asynctask and in this I am calling the following method to add marker

```
addMarker(Double.parseDouble(latitude), Double.parseDouble(longitude));
```

addMarker Function is as follows :

public void addMarker(Double Lat, Double Long) {

```
 if (null != googleMap) {
           MyMapFragment.this.googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(new LatLng(Lat, Long))
                            .title("You")
                            .draggable(true)


            );
}
}
```

this is good as it is showing the markers successfully but I know this is not the right thing to do as I wanted each marker to show its own other specific information , so for doing this I know I have to save the information of markers but I don't know how to do it

**What I want **

What I want is to save each pin/marker record against it and on click of that marker open its information in a new window or activity so How can I achieve this , Please share me an code to get the idea or please redirect me to an easy code I do know about the demo project on github But I am not able to understand it as it is complex for me . Please help

Comment: I also in need of something like it

Comment: Take a look at this answer, it is relevant to what you are doing and it might help get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30601892/android-google-maps-marker-infowindow-activities/30602598#30602598

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot add metadata to your markers. What you need to do instead - is to save markers as you add them to some data structure in form of map (`<Marker, Model>`), so you can retrieve model based on marker.

Let's assume you have a `Model` class which defines Hotel information.  In this case, you can have a map of objects to keep track of your markers:

```
Map<Marker, Model> markerMap = new HashMap<Marker, Model>();
```

Now as you add markers, just put them in this map:

```
public void addMarker(Model hotelModel) {

    if (null != googleMap) {
        Marker hotelMarker = MyMapFragment.this.googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(hotelModel.getLat(), hotelModel.getLon()))
                        .title(hotelModel.getTitle())
        );

        markerMap.add(hotelMarker, hotelModel);
    }
}
```

Now when marker is clicked, you can get hotel model based on the marker object:

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick (Marker marker) {
    Model hotelModel = markerMap.get(marker);
    if(hotelModel != null) {
        Log.d("test", "Hotel "+hotelModel.getTitle()+" is clicked"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: i am getting you point a little and this is really what I want , so you are saying me to make a class let assume HotelModel and it should have getter setter of all that fields that I am getting from the service Right ?

Comment: and How about to adding them what should we pass when calling the addmarkerFunction ?

Comment: @CoasMckey yes, just create a class which holds all the data you retrieved from service and specify getters and setters for it

Comment: @stacyqueen you call addMarker the same way as before. Just store the result of this method into map

Comment: and how about saving info in this class in Asynctask , whould it be like ,
Model myModel = new Model():
myModel.Hotelname = HotelNameFromService?

Comment: @CoasMckey sure, it can look like that

Comment: I was adding  it by sending just latitude and longitude in your case of addMarker i think now I should not send latitude and longitude what should I send then , what I was doing was
 addMarker(Double.parseDouble(latitude), Double.parseDouble(longitude));

Comment: but it would save information of one marker at a time and then the information of second marker would be over written on it ? is it so ?

Comment: I have request and that is please show some more code and eloborate it please please please

Comment: @CoasMckey no, it would not be overridden. 'markerMap' will store as many model objects as you have. And based on clicked marker it will return the proper model

Comment: I think this is best answr

Comment: how to use Marker Click ?

Comment: @PavelDudka I have implemented all things including click listener but there is problem in click when I click other markers of hotel All are returning me the name of last hotel  marker added on map ,
if(hotelModel != null) {
        Log.d("test", "Hotel "+hotelModel.getTitle()+" is clicked"); 
    }

Comment: @CoasMckey cannot help much without seeing your implementation. Looks like you are using map wrong. Are you recreating it every time you add a marker?

Comment: No I am not recreating it , infact I am using the same map , , I have implemented all things and every thing is working fine , I can see my pins and info window name on them , but click is not wokring though

Comment: where should I write this line ? 
googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);

Comment: @CoasMckey you set onClickListener right where you initialize the GoogleMap

Comment: I did as you said , but problem is , let suppose my last hotel marker that was added was named LSM , so on  clicking every marker I got the name LSM ,  but when I remove the click listener I can see the info window when I click on any marker and it shows the name of each marker exactly they way it is saved

Comment: @CoasMckey it seems like you are reusing your Model object rather than creating unique one for each hotel instance. Thats why in your map all markers point to the same model instance

Comment: I think I got the problem In First I was creating the model instance in onCreateview , now I am creating its instance in the service Where i am storing information , now it is working as expected

Comment: So same rule would be apply if I want to make click for the info wiondow ? right ?

Comment: @CoasMckey, yes infowindow clicks should be handled similarly