# Android Studio Multiple Marker Listener

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

im developing android apps with multiple map and direction, the users can choose who cars in the map and show direction.

i confuse with listener each marker(not infowindow), i wanna user to choose marker and automatic route direction to current location. i have done with routes and multiple marker, but i cant change route each cars. it always endup with last array of cars, here my array marker :

```
 @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
    {

LatLng[] point_new = new LatLng[3];
point_new[0] = new LatLng(-7.7827567,110.364876);
point_new[1] = new LatLng(-7.8061627,110.3859053);
point_new[2] = new LatLng(-7.7872971, 110.3858244);
 for (int i = 0; i < point_new.length; i++) {
            mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(point_new[i])
                    .title("Cars")
                    .snippet("Type:Economic")
                    .icon((BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.cars)))
            );

            sessionManager = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
            sessionManager.createSession(point_new[i].toString());
            MapLocationActivity.this.setSomeDestinasi(point_new[i]);
            mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(point_new[i]));
        }
  }
```

and my onclick marker code :

```
@Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {

        if (marker.equals(mGoogleMap))
        {
            //handle click here
            requestDirection();
         sessionManager = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
        HashMap<String, String> user = sessionManager.getUserDetails();
        String carslocation = user.get(SessionManager.key_latlon);

        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MapLocationActivity.this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
        alertDialog.setMessage(carslocation);
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.show();
        }

        return true;
    }
```

i use sharedpreference to store dynamic routes lat and long, the question is how i make marker[i] on click?

```
 if (marker.equals(marker[i]))
        {
}

 marker+i =  mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()

);
```

note : i use akexorcist google direction library

thanks

Comment: `if(marker.equals(mGoogleMap))`? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Looks like this answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31630967/4409409