# Android-Google Maps V2-Adding custom infowindows to markers created from an array

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I want to create an app which can receive a set of points from a database and add markers for each point on a map. I am currently using an object array for testing purposes. I have used the same marker variable in a loop to put the markers on the map.

The array which contains my marker positions also contains some other data about those specific locations which I want to bring up in a custom infowindow (which gets its data from the array) when the markers are touched.

I am unsure of how I should differentiate between the different markers in calling this infowindow.

[OnMarkerClickListener document on developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener)

My code for adding markers:

```
for (pointNumber= 0; pointNumber<pointArray.length; pointNumber++) {
    taxiLatitude = pointArray[pointNumber].position.latitude;
    taxiLongitude = pointArray[pointNumber].position.longitude;

    if (valueInArray<someValue) {
        pointMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(pointArray[pointNumber].position.latitude, carsArray[pointNumber].position.longitude))
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN))
            .title("Title: "+pointArray[pointNumber].pointTitle)
            .snippet("Snippet: "+pointArray[pointNumber].pointSnippet));
    } else {
        System.out.println("Out of range");
    }
}
```

My code to add data to my custom infowindow, which I got [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Google-Maps-API-v2-Usage)

```
class CustomWindowAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {
    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    public CustomWindowAdapter(LayoutInflater i){
        mInflater = i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        // Getting view from the layout file
        View v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_window_layout, null);
        // Populate fields
        ImageView image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);
        image.setImageResource(pointArray[pointNumber].image);

        TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_1);
        title.setText(pointArray[pointNumber].text1);

        TextView description = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_2);
        description.setText(pointArray[pointNumber].text2);
        }
        // Return info window contents
        return v;      

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This might help, use a HashMap: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30602617

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement a HashMap, realx, is easy, I'll show you how do that to identify all your markers:

Create the HashMap with key type String and object type Marker:

```
HashMap<String,Marker> hashMarkers = new HashMap<>();
```

Add the markers to the hash map identified by number (converted to string):

```
for (int x= 0; x < yourArray.length; x++) {
        hashMarkers.put(String.valueOf(x), mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position( your array (or arrays) of positions(s) )
    }
```

Then you can identify every marker you want:

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                    if (marker.equals(hashMarkers.get("the number of the marker"))) {
                        //here you can call your custom infoWindow or set the content 
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I get the infowindow pertaining to each marker to be displayed when a marker is clicked?

Comment: The last block of code is for that, you have to set only one marker click listener, iside the listener is the `if (marker.equals(hashMarkers.get("the number of the marker")))` to distinguish every marker