# oninfowindowclick used only with only marker info in case of multiple markers

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-markers

I've made a loop to create multiple markers , but the onInfoWindowClickListener works for all the markers with one parameters

```
 for ( i = 0; i < MyArrListx.size(); i++) {

        n = Double.parseDouble(MyArrListx.get(i));
        e = Double.parseDouble(MyArrListy.get(i));
      final String phone = (MyArrListphonenumber.get(i));
         map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(n, e)) .title("Click to Call Transporter !!").snippet( phone )
              .position(new LatLng(n, e)))
                .setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
               map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {


                if (marker.getSnippet().equals(phone)) // if marker source is clicked
                    dialContactPhone(phone);


            }
        });
```

It calls the number of the first marker snippet only, with all the marker in time that each snippet contains a different number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the call to `setOnInfoWindowClickListener()` out of the loop, there is only one InfoWindowClickListener for the map, and it is used for all Markers.

Then, just get the phone number from the snippet in the `OnInfoWindowClickListener`.

This should be sufficient for your needs:

```
for ( i = 0; i < MyArrListx.size(); i++) {
  n = Double.parseDouble(MyArrListx.get(i));
  e = Double.parseDouble(MyArrListy.get(i));
  String phone = (MyArrListphonenumber.get(i));
  map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(n, e)) 
                .title("Click to Call Transporter !!").snippet( phone )
                .position(new LatLng(n, e)))
                .setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
}



map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

            //Just get the phone number stored in the snippet, and dial
            String phone = marker.getSnippet();
            dialContactPhone(phone);
        }
    });
```

Note, if you need to do something more complicated than just what you can store in the Title and Snippet, then use a HashMap to store your data, and use the Marker ID as the keys of the HashMap, see here for more info:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30602617/4409409

Comment: i wannaaaa kisssss yaaa ,,, thanx a lot maaan you made my dayyy